# ls command - on progressive chunks in linux - large directory

Tags: python, linux, powershell, shell

I have problem of listing files from really big directory.

`ls -l *.pdf` command is taking lot of time and for every disconnection its starting from first.

i have tried few things

```
ls -l /**/*.pdf
```

and

```
find ./*.pdf -type d -maxdepth 1 -printf '%f\n' >> files.txt
```

and

```
glob.glob(f"{dir}/**/*.pdf", recursive=True)
```

these are taking hours without any acknowledgement of progress.

is there any way to list the files in progressive manner from chunks of directory and to resume from the place its completed in a single directory. So it would be helpful to resume from there even in disconnections than to start from first.

I spent time exploring many blogs, but it didn't help.

`displit` - may have chance
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247353/314903

any small suggestions or leads would highly appreciated.

Comment: I checked this, but its also not helping - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247353/314903

Comment: Roughly, how many files are there in the dir and how many of them pdf files?

Comment: By "disconnection", do you mean you're in a remote shell? If so, you might want to consider tmux or screen so that your shell session continues.

Comment: around 8 million files with each file size 1 to 25 mb size @Jay

Comment: @DanGetz Yes, actually its a physical drive i am connecting from the other source, its like network disconnection. :-|

Comment: My guess is you can't resume if the drive is being disconnected. But that `find` command could be better written to not have the shell do wildcard expansion before it starts

Comment: What I meant by "can't" is that the standard libraries' directory searches aren't restartable like you want. It's probably possible to write a restartable directory search by using libraries for the specific file system your drive uses. But that's probably overkill for what you're doing.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/123440/66663

Comment: `ls` and `glob` both take a fair amount of time just sorting the directory entries. `os.scandir` should be somewhat faster because it does not try to sort anything, but then `find` doesn't sort anything either. At the end of the day, you probably are running up against limits of the Linux file system you are using. Maybe try with btrfs or zfs if you are currently on ext4, or reorganize the directory's contents so that files with a particular prefix are in a subdirectory whose name is that prefix (aka hashing, though the term is significantly overloaded with a number of other meanings, too).

Comment: `find -name '*.pdf' -type d -maxdepth 1 -printf '%f\n' >> files.txt` should be faster; but do you really have directories whose names match that pattern?

Comment: Yes, folder is mostly with only pdf records data @tripleee, my main concern is to resuming operation, even if i did it for few records.

Comment: Like others have told you already, there is no way to do that with standard tools. Maybe manually run a loop over the possible prefixes and report on the progress in each iteration, though that would then end up traversing the directory many times instead of once.